# No sound on Chromecast with Netflix

Tags: chromecast, audio, streaming

I just bought a new Thomson 32HD3331 TV and a Chromecast 3 device and I'm having a really strange sound issue in Netflix.

For most films, I'm not getting any sound, but I do for a few (e.g. South Park). Other apps have no issue (e.g. YouTube), but when I try to play a film from Netflix, I only hear a glitch, then silence (no white noise). I tried to play around with audio settings on my TV unsuccessfully. I also tried with my older Chromecast 1, with the same results.

Any idea?

Comment: This doesn't really look on topic here.

Comment: Why not? Where is more appropriate?